# Visual studio 2010 IDE layout

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My current visual studio panel layout looks similar to the drawing below:

```
-----------------  
|  |         |  |  
|  |         |  |  
|  |         |  |  
|  |         |--|  
|  |         |  |  
|  |---------|  |  
|  |         |  |  
-----------------
```

I really don't need the full height of the screen for the toolbox or server explorer and was wondering if there was a way to change the layout so that the bottom section extended all the way to the left edge of the screen like in this drawing:

```
-----------------
|  |         |  |
|  |         |  |
|  |         |  |
|  |         |--|
|  |         |  |
|------------|  |
|            |  |
-----------------
```

I am space constrained on the right side, so a symetric layout with the bottom section running full width wouldn't be acceptable.  I've tried dragging stuff around but haven't had any luck in getting VS to position the panels as I want.  Is my desired layout not possible or am I missing the right way to coax the layout into fitting?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use auto-hide?  Then you get full size on both right and bottom when you need them, and they're gone when you don't.

Comment: Autohide drives me crazy by opening when I overshoot the edge of the text window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. When you are dragging the toolbox, note the little "targets" in the center of the screen. Drop the toolbox onto the target that corresponds with the area where you want it docked.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4y0hsax.aspx) for more detail and pics.

Answer (score 1):

Drag the bottom panel off and make sure to mouse over the icon that appears all the way at the bottom center of the screen, although this will cause it to take up the whole bottom portion of the IDE,

Comment: I specifically said I don't want it spanning the full width on the right.

Comment: once you've done what I said simply take the properties box/solution explorer or whatever is there and place it over the rightmost box that pops up and voila you should have what you want.

Comment: I see now.  That only works if nothing else is docked to the right side.  I had the solution explorer on top of the properties dialog; but neglected to put it in my drawings because I was under the mistaken impression that it was excess detail.  Getting it to stick your way requires me to pull both of them off before reattaching them.

Comment: It can be a pain sometimes but that's how it is with Visual Studio, and your setup is exactly like mine as well.

Answer (score 0):

[image]That's an easy process.

1. Drag the window docked in the bottom to middle of the VS window so that it floats in the middle.
2. Now when you drag it, a helper would apper to doc it.
3. You'll have some dynamic docking helpers like below.

   ```
                          ↑    
                          ↑
   ←                       ← →                              →
                          ↓
                          ↓
   ```
4. if you chose the downarrow in the dock helper in the middle, you'll get the layout like this.

---

```
|  |         |  |            
|  |         |  |            
|  |         |  |            
|  |         |--|            
|  |         |  |            
|  |---------|  |            
|  |         |  |            
-----------------
```

5. If you chose the downarrow all the way at the bottom, you'll get the layout like this.

---

```
|  |         |  |           
|  |         |  |           
|  |         |  |           
|  |         |--|           
|  |         |  |           
|---------------|           
|               |           
-----------------
```